# No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=armv6 armv7)

Tags: objective-c, xcode3.2

I have an Xcode 3.2.5 project with two targets.  The first is a vanilla iOS target.  The second is targeted to the Mac.  Here is the project description:

```
    92936A04148FEE15001C4EC6 /* Debug */ = {
        isa = XCBuildConfiguration;
        buildSettings = {
            ADDITIONAL_SDKS = "";
            ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS = NO;
            ARCHS = "$(NATIVE_ARCH_ACTUAL)";
            COPY_PHASE_STRIP = NO;
            GCC_DYNAMIC_NO_PIC = NO;
            GCC_ENABLE_FIX_AND_CONTINUE = YES;
            GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = 0;
            GCC_PRECOMPILE_PREFIX_HEADER = NO;
            GCC_PREFIX_HEADER = SleepSoundCommand_Prefix.pch;
            GENERATE_PKGINFO_FILE = NO;
            INFOPLIST_FILE = "SleepSoundCommand-Info.plist";
            INSTALL_PATH = "$(HOME)/Applications";
            ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = YES;
            OTHER_LDFLAGS = "";
            PREBINDING = NO;
            PRIVATE_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH = "";
            PRODUCT_NAME = SleepSoundCommand;
            PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH = "";
            SDKROOT = "";
            VALID_ARCHS = "i386 ppc ppc64 ppc7400 ppc970 x86_64";
        };
        name = Debug;
    };
```

Problem is, when I attempt to build I get

`No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=armv6 armv7).`

Why is it insisting that "VALID_ARCHS=armv6 armv7"?

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it insisting that "VALID_ARCHS=armv6 armv7"?

Mixing Mac and iOS targets in an Xcode project has always been tricky.

I suspect that your problem is related to the use of SDKs.  If you are using an iOS SDK and targeting an iOS device somewhere, it'll require `arm*`.  Make sure that the SDK settings aren't leaking through to the Mac target(s).

Also -- if at all possible, you should upgrade to the latest Xcode.  Tons of bug fixes since the relatively ancient 3.2...

Comment: Really?  Dang.  That's a bug. File it, please!

Comment: It seems like the design to me.  Whatever window has focus gets reformed.  Your neatly laid out windows for code and console get scrambled.