# an error "No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=armv7 armv7s)."?

Tags: objective-c, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I have Xcode 4.6. I downloaded [this project](https://github.com/nikolaypavlov/MLPNeuralNet) When run it i receive a message
`No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=armv7 armv7s).` 
Where and what i have to change? I have no idea what should i do? Thanx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8478291/no-architectures-to-compile-for-only-active-arch-yes-active-arch-x86-64-valid?rq=1 please see this link

Answer (score 19):

If you are in Xcode 5.0 , this may arise if you select a 64 bit (simulator for iPhone 5S) simulator instead of 32 bit simulator. 
This happened to me. It may help some one, because I didn't find any answer to solve this till I found it myself.

Answer (score 12):

Go to
 **Project Target > Build Settings > Architectures**

and make

**Build Active Architecture Only = NO**

The issue will be solved

Comment: This worked for my project. Can you expand your answer to explain why this works?

Answer (score 4):

For me the solution was to add arm64 to valid arhitectures.
Follow steps described in the attached image.
Hope it helps someone[image]

Answer (score 3):

Change the following:

Build Settings > Architectures > Architectures to:

**"$(ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=armv7 armv7s)"**

Build Settings > Architectures > Valid Architectures to:

**armv7 armv7s**

Build Settings > Architectures > Build Active Architectures Only to:

**No**

Answer (score 1):

change the Target--Build Settings--Architectures To "Standard(armv7,armv7s)"

Answer (score 0):

In the Build setting you need to change the architecture to your project architecture which it supports

Comment: Thank you. But in Build settings->Architectures i had $(ARCHS_STANDARD_INCLUDING_64_BIT) and i changed it on $(ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=armv7 armv7s)  I got a same error.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the following ONLY works for me:

Build Settings > Architectures > Valid Architectures to:

armv7 armv7s