# No architectures to compile for (archs= valid_archs=armv7 armv7s): OS 10.8.3 ios 6.1.3

Tags: iphone, xcode, architecture, cocos2d-x, armv7

I have an app using cocos2d-x and it is working with iOS 6.1 Simulator. However I cannot test it in my device because of the following error:

"no architectures to compile for (archs= valid_archs=armv7 armv7s)".

I tried the sugestions of:

[iPhone Compiler Fails: No architectures to compile for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549478/iphone-compiler-fails-no-architectures-to-compile-for)

[No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=armv7 armv7s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889065/no-architectures-to-compile-for-only-active-arch-yes-active-arch-x86-64-valid)

[an error "No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=armv7 armv7s)."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19423800/an-error-no-architectures-to-compile-for-only-active-arch-yes-active-arch-x86)

None of this has worked.

Info:
Mac: OS 10.8.3 / Iphone 4: iOS 6.1.3 / Xcode: 4.6.3

Answer (score 1):

(Solution from the OP):

> The problems was that the Architectures on Build Settings of a
>   specific Target of Cocos2d was set as `$(ARCHS_STANDARD)`, different
>   from `Standard (armv7 armv7s)` set on Project Build Settings. I just
>   set the Architectures on Target Build Settings equal to the Project
>   Build Settings ( `Standard (armv7 armv7s)`  ) and the problem was
>   fixed.