# ERROR ITMS-9000: "Unsupported architectures. Your executable contains unsupported architectures '[x86_64, i386]'"

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store-connect, xcode6

It is impossible to send in itunesconnect new version of the application. Although last week, the same version send happened. In the code, I just changed the name of a button, no more changes are not made ​​where. 
But always get error:

**ERROR ITMS-9000: "Unsupported architectures. Your executable contains unsupported architectures '[x86_64, i386]'"**

In my project -> Build Settings:
ARCHS = $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)
//:configuration = Debug
ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = YES
//:configuration = Release
ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = NO

VALID_ARCHS = armv7 armv7s

Comment: Make sure you have "iOS device" selected as your target at the top of the Xcode window - you are trying to submit a simulator build

Comment: @Paulw11 It set my iPhone. I'm build a project on it, it all goes well. Then do the archive and try to send a itunescoonect, the result is the same.

Comment: You need to check carefully your build settings or roll back from version control and try again - For some reason you are generating an x86 build

Comment: Check Product -> Scheme -> Edit scheme... -> Archive. It has to say Build Configuration: "Release".

Comment: By the way, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19423800/1166894

Comment: @neutrino and there is.

Comment: I experience the same issue and didn't find out how to fix it, a week ago it was everything fine.

Comment: @AntonAnisimov I still can not solve this problem, if you find any solutions please let me know.

Comment: @AntonAnisimov you use YandeksMapKit in your project? I think the problem is in it.

Comment: I had used ShareKit, but the idea was to start removing of the Cocoapods or other libraries to find what doesn't work and I did find that it was ShareKit, because it used LiveSDK.

Comment: It could be any library that you've using right now, just try to remove them and see what it cause do that.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Check out this slick solution on Daniel Kennett's blog - it worked perfectly for me with the SpritzSDK, which I had similar issues with.

He supplies a script you can drop-in to your build phases to strip out the unwanted architectures as a last step - doesn't break the simulator, and iTunesConnect approved my upload as well on the first try.

http://ikennd.ac/blog/2015/02/stripping-unwanted-architectures-from-dynamic-libraries-in-xcode/

Comment: Run script only when installing? or no?

Comment: The script goes into the build phase, so only when building

Comment: How come some of frameworks don't require this script and still manage to build and run both in Simulator and actual devices?

Answer (score 19):

You can remove unwanted ARCHS from IPA by putting below peace of Shell Script in Build Phase -- > RUN Script 
This Script removes all simulator ARCHS from IPA and ARCH issues from Embedded framework. 
Source :
http://ikennd.ac/blog/2015/02/stripping-unwanted-architectures-from-dynamic-libraries-in-xcode/

```
APP_PATH="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}"

# This script loops through the frameworks embedded in the application and
# removes unused architectures.
find "$APP_PATH" -name '*.framework' -type d | while read -r FRAMEWORK
do
    FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME=$(defaults read "$FRAMEWORK/Info.plist" CFBundleExecutable)
    FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH="$FRAMEWORK/$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
    echo "Executable is $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

    EXTRACTED_ARCHS=()

    for ARCH in $ARCHS
    do
        echo "Extracting $ARCH from $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
        lipo -extract "$ARCH" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH"
        EXTRACTED_ARCHS+=("$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH")
    done

    echo "Merging extracted architectures: ${ARCHS}"
    lipo -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" -create "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"
    rm "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"

    echo "Replacing original executable with thinned version"
    rm "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
    mv "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

done
```

Comment: Please don't take it personally. If you are coping an intellectual property from someone else, please be kind enough to give the credit back to the original creator. In this case, http://ikennd.ac/blog/2015/02/stripping-unwanted-architectures-from-dynamic-libraries-in-xcode/

Comment: @Goppinath  Edited.My Answer. Thanks for Suggestion.

Comment: @arpen_techisavy Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The script in the above two answers needs to be edited if you have an watch app in your project. Add /Frameworks to the $APP_PATH to avoid errors when building the project.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using LiveSDK directly or via ShareKit, you will run into this problem. In my case I was using LiveSDK directly.

Check this answer on Apple Developer Forum

https://devforums.apple.com/message/1037603#1037603

Comment: I am experiencing this same issue, I'm not using LiveSDK or ShareKit. Nothing seems to help.

Comment: My issue was caused by the Urban Airship SDK. :/

Comment: @Mohan Thank you. Indeed all was well, as soon as I removed LiveSDK!

Comment: Hi how did you resolve this issue for live sdk.
No answer in the link helped

Comment: how do I solve the issue if I used Urban Airship @Pax

Comment: Urban Airship includes unnecessary libs, you need to delete the ones that are not needed for your version of IOS before compiling.