# ERROR ITMS-9000: “Unsupported architectures.Xcode Archive error

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6, live-sdk

I am trying to upload my app to the appstore.
Have done that successfully in the past but after integrating live sdk i get this error-
    ERROR ITMS-9000: “Unsupported architectures. Your executable contains unsupported architectures     '[x86_64, i386]'”
I cant even get past the validation screen.
Any help would be highly appreciated.
I tried a few suggestion mentioned here-

[ERROR ITMS-9000: "Unsupported architectures. Your executable contains unsupported architectures '[x86_64, i386]'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25886643/error-itms-9000-unsupported-architectures-your-executable-contains-unsupporte)

But even this did not help
Thanks in advance.

Cheers
Nitesh

Comment: Have you solved this? I am facing the same problem right now.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when I tried to submit the ipa, we can't upload frameworks with simulator arquitectures  i386 & x86_64 to itunes connect

In my case was because of  frameworks of Carthage has i386 & 86_64 arquitectures

Then, you can try 2 options:

**1.- If Carthage case** > Read carthage [Readme file here](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage#if-youre-building-for-ios-tvos-or-watchos)

Where they explains how to workaround this [App Store submission bug](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=6409498411401216):

```
On your application targets’ “Build Phases” settings tab, click the “+” 
icon and choose “New Run Script Phase”. Create a Run Script with the following contents: 

/usr/local/bin/carthage copy-frameworks 

and add the paths to the frameworks you want to use under “Input Files”,
e.g.: 

$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/Box.framework
$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/Result.framework
$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/ReactiveCocoa.framework
```

**2.- Remove the arquitectures that you don't need to upload**

Here you have a solution with a really nice script to remove arquitectures that you don't need
[Submit to App Store issues: Unsupported Architecture x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547283/submit-to-app-store-issues)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by adding armv6 in the supported architectures. This worked for me.