# Submit to App Store issues: Unsupported Architecture x86

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, app-store-connect, x86-64

So I am trying to use the Shopify API. When I archive the app and validate it then there are no issues but when I submit it to the app store then it gives me the following issues.

1. ERROR ITMS-90087: "Unsupported Architecture. Your executable contains unsupported architecture '[x86_64, i386]'."
2. ERROR ITMS-90209: "Invalid segment Alignment. The App Binary at SJAPP.app/Frameworks/Buy.framework/Buy does not have proper segment alignment. Try rebuilding the app with the latest Xcode version." (I am already using the latest version.)
3. ERROR ITMS-90125: "The Binary is invalid. The encryption info in the LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO load command is either missing or invalid, or the binary is already encrypted. This binary does not seem to have been built with Apple's Linker."
4. WARNING ITMS-90080: "The Executable Payload/..../Buy.framework is not a Position Independent Executable. Please ensure that ur build settings are configured to create PIE executables."

Comment: The first message sounds as if it's a simulator build.

Comment: When i create an archive for submission i choose the iOS devices in the devices options then create an archive, if thats what u are asking

Comment: I agree with @PhillipMills. Concentrate on your first error. _Why_ do you have a x86_64 binary in your iOS app? Either you've done something weird with your build settings... or you uploaded a Simulator build.

Comment: @pAkY88. I was not able to. I recently posted in the Shopify API forum and am awaiting a response. Will definitely post something if I come across one

Comment: I had this behaviour when I uploaded using Application Loader 3.5

Comment: For better context see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28033635/why-does-the-ios-simulator-require-i386-and-x86-64-symbols-even-though-im-on-an)

Answer (score 419, accepted):

The problem is that the Buy framework contains a build for both the simulator (x86_64) and the actual devices (ARM).

Of course, you aren't allowed to submit to the App Store a binary for an unsupported architecture, so the solution is to "manually" remove the unneeded architectures from the final binary, before submitting it.

Daniel Kennett came up with [a nice solution and provides this script](http://ikennd.ac/blog/2015/02/stripping-unwanted-architectures-from-dynamic-libraries-in-xcode/) to add to the build phase:

```
APP_PATH="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}"

# This script loops through the frameworks embedded in the application and
# removes unused architectures.
find "$APP_PATH" -name '*.framework' -type d | while read -r FRAMEWORK
do
    FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME=$(defaults read "$FRAMEWORK/Info.plist" CFBundleExecutable)
    FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH="$FRAMEWORK/$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
    echo "Executable is $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

    EXTRACTED_ARCHS=()

    for ARCH in $ARCHS
    do
        echo "Extracting $ARCH from $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
        lipo -extract "$ARCH" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH"
        EXTRACTED_ARCHS+=("$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH")
    done

    echo "Merging extracted architectures: ${ARCHS}"
    lipo -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" -create "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"
    rm "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"

    echo "Replacing original executable with thinned version"
    rm "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
    mv "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

done
```

I used it and it worked perfectly.

EDIT: make sure you look at the modified script posted by Varrry, as this one has some minor issues.

Comment: @pAkY88 I've used this script in my Xcode project to fix up the App Store Issues mentioned above, but now when I go to Build, I have alot of fatal errors -> fatal error: lipo: input file (/...Frameworks/Bolts.framework/Bolts) must be a fat file when the -extract option is specified. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I think it's pretty stupid: you have to combine arm+x86 to allow your app runs on both simulator and device, and have to strip x86 out to submit to app store. Why Apple doesn't do the strip on their end as long as x86 is detected? They can help a lot of technical reasons to defend this, but none business reason since it's not user friendly at all.

Comment: @fancy yes, check out my post on how I fixed my issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240330/errors-building-xcode-project-after-adding-in-run-script-fatal-error-lipo-inpu

Comment: I'm not sure where should I put this script. Should I edit the Build scheme and add it in Post-actions?

Comment: @Skoua Select the relevant target, then "Build Phases" and put it after the "Embed Frameworks" action

Comment: @SamoanProgrammer Has a valid point, to run the script only for specific framework for which you get x86_64 error and not for all frameworks.

Comment: Works great but I get the following message when I send the binary to iTunes connect: Too many symbol files - These symbols have no corresponding slice in any binary. Then I have to uncheck the upload symbol files to avoid the warnings.

Comment: I am getting the error "find: ftsopen: No such file or directory" when I use this script, any ideas? I've create a question for it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40655588/xcode-remove-architectures-run-script-is-showing-find-ftsopen-no-such-file-or

Comment: Is it possible to add this script within framework that is vender side?

Comment: To extract arm64 slice, lipo from the iOS toolchain should be used, not from the host system: xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -info FILENAME

Comment: Worked perfectly. Is it a fair assumption that anyone using a third party framework who wants to upload their build to iTunes Connect needs this script?

Comment: WHAT ARE THE STEPS? Should i change the Script's "APP_PATH"?

APP_PATH="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}"

can anyone write an example please? what are the steps? should i run it from the "Terminal?" @pAkY88

Comment: Its not working when i archive the build. It says unsupported architectue i386 i.e. the script is not stripping the simulator architecture.

Comment: Make sure this run script is the last item in your Build Phases.

Comment: @James111 I'm struggling to remember. Something like if you check framework search paths in build settings and make sure all the folders actually exist.

Comment: have you tested on Xcode 9? I test in Xcode9 and it´s not working (archiving), any idea how make it work?

Comment: Followed all the steps still doesnt work for me. I am trying on xcode 8.1 and using AdobeCreativeSDKCore. Can anyone suggest what could be wrong in my case?

Comment: yeeh you saved my time.. Its worked for me... just for specific framework also just replace * with framework name.. Thank you so much

Comment: Nice touch to this, MiTek copied your script, added it to their FAQ and added line breaks ... Guess someone "copied" your work badly

Comment: The above script is helpful but nowhere mentioned about steps to run the script in Xcode. To run this script goto TARGETS --> select Build Phases then upper header in Xcode tap on Editor --> Add build phases --> Add run script Build phases and you will get an column in Build Phase section of TARGET. Here you can copy paste above script and upload it to Appstore successfully.

Comment: Hey, this script caused me huge headaches recently. If you include a watch app in Xcode 10 _this script nukes your watch app frameworks_! That's because the `ARCHS` variable doesn't include the watch architectures and starting in Xcode 10, watch frameworks are fat. So this script will completely remove them.

Comment: Not working in Xcode 11.2 - anyone found a solution?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I haven't had the chance (and I hope I never will) to test this workaround on XCode 11.2, hope someone can post an update solution.

Comment: I dont understand one thing, if apple rejects unused architectures, so how popular frameworks manage to do this? like Alamofire or swiftyJson. They both run in simulator and device and no any error while submitting app to app store which included this frameworks. Thank you.

Comment: Hi friends, above mentioned answer's script is correct, the tricky part is where to place it, that work for upload app using archive with strip and slice. Edit Scheme -> Archive -> open dropdown -> post actions -> + to add new script -> copy and paste enjoy. :)

Comment: @pAkY88 IMPORTANT: Now in the new M1 macs the simulator architecture is arm64, so this script removes everything from new xcframeworks and frameworks. Thats why IPA will always fail to install.
!!!!!WARNING!!!!!

Answer (score 210):

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30866648/5272316) given by pAkY88 works, but I faced the same problem as Mario A Guzman in https://stackoverflow.com/a/35240555/5272316: once we cut off unused architectures we can't run script any more since it tries to remove not existing slices, because xcode doesn't re-embed binary every time.
Idea was - just remove i386 and x86_64 slices when building for archive, so I modified script:

```
echo "Target architectures: $ARCHS"

APP_PATH="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}"

find "$APP_PATH" -name '*.framework' -type d | while read -r FRAMEWORK
do
FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME=$(defaults read "$FRAMEWORK/Info.plist" CFBundleExecutable)
FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH="$FRAMEWORK/$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
echo "Executable is $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
echo $(lipo -info "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH")

FRAMEWORK_TMP_PATH="$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-tmp"

# remove simulator's archs if location is not simulator's directory
case "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}" in
*"iphonesimulator")
    echo "No need to remove archs"
    ;;
*)
    if $(lipo "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" -verify_arch "i386") ; then
    lipo -output "$FRAMEWORK_TMP_PATH" -remove "i386" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
    echo "i386 architecture removed"
    rm "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
    mv "$FRAMEWORK_TMP_PATH" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
    fi
    if $(lipo "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" -verify_arch "x86_64") ; then
    lipo -output "$FRAMEWORK_TMP_PATH" -remove "x86_64" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
    echo "x86_64 architecture removed"
    rm "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
    mv "$FRAMEWORK_TMP_PATH" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
    fi
    ;;
esac

echo "Completed for executable $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
echo $(lipo -info "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH")

done
```

This script simply removes i386 and x86_64 slices from fat binary (if they exist) if running not for simulator (that means destination folder isn't like "Debug-iphonesimulator").

Sorry, I'm not familiar with shell scripts, so may be someone could write it more elegant way. But it works)

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I've simply added a check to the code from the accepted answer inside the while loop `case "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}" in
*"iphonesimulator") echo "Skip simulator target"; continue ;;
esac` and it worked like a charm.

Comment: I am adding this script in `TARGET -> Build Phases -> [CP] Embedded Pods Frameworks` but it doesn't work and I have still upload to iTunesConnect errors. How to run this script?

Comment: PiterPan, add it as separate RunScript phase

Comment: I just checked the "Run script only when installing" option and it gets skipped except then archiving.

Comment: Did everything suggested here, managed to clear the Carthage error; but needed to upload it the App Store without validation to get some useful information as to why it failed. Managed to fix that and moving forward...

Comment: have you tested on Xcode 9? I test in Xcode9 and it´s not working (archiving), any idea how make it work?

Comment: @magofdl, I currently can't check this, could you provide more details on issue?

Comment: @Varrry I have notice that the TARGET_BUILD_DIR has changed while archiving in Xcode 9, I don't know if thats correct or a bug in Xcode 9, so the script can't find the frameworks on that path

Comment: @magofdl, since frameworks are inside app wrapper (*.APP dir), script shouldn't depend on target build dir location. I think your problem lays somewhere else; need more details: errors, logs, etc.

Comment: @Varrry you can fin the log from the script [here](https://jpst.it/17J92) , I added the app path to the log before the find command, I have notice that on the  archive the script is not logging the "Executable is ..." only the app path.

Comment: @magofdl from logs I see you use original script posted by pAkY88, not this script above.
Anyway, I'd advice you to create new question with reference to this answer and mentioning me (or pAkY88 if you wish), to avoid overflowing comments here with side question. In your question you can provide full info on your issue: what frameworks do you use, which archs, what are you doing and what happens as a result.

Comment: @Varrry thank you, I have posted a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47577524/shell-script-for-remove-the-unneeded-architectures-while-archiving-not-working)

Comment: add this script in Project --> Run Script.
Reinstall pods, clean existing data/user data.
Now it's working

Comment: I have problems using this when building for my device. "... must be a fat file when the -extract option is specified".

Comment: @JorisMans are you sure you use this script and not original one? This script is specially to avoid problem you mentioned.

Comment: Yes. Your script solves the problem when building for the simulator. Not for the actual device : case "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}" in
*"iphonesimulator")

Comment: @JorisMans, there aren't problems building for simulator, simulator allows using binaries with not supported archs; problem appears only when building for AppStore and this is the case \*), where all work is done; error you mentioned sometimes appears running original script (see comment by SamoanProgrammer to original script) and shouldn't appear while running *this* script since -extract option is not used there. This script doesn't *extract* slices but only *removes* slices from binary, so I can't understand how you could face such error.

Comment: I am not talking about the simulator. i am talking about running it on the device, in debug build

Comment: @JorisMans, ok, what else do you see in script's output? Did you find at which point it fails?

Comment: Sorry, can't help anymore with that. We've since removed the third party library that required using this script so I don't use it anymore.

Comment: I had to add it again:
This is when building in debug for a device:
Extracting arm64 from Protobuf
fatal error: lipo: input file (/Debug-iphoneos/***.app/Frameworks/Protobuf.framework/Protobuf) must be a fat file when the -extract option is specified

Comment: I managed to fix it by adding:

if lipo -info "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" | grep 'Non-fat file'; then
    continue
fi

Comment: @JorisMans did you get which string in the script causes error? I don't understand, -extract option isn't used there

Comment: @Varrry If my framework contains another supporting framework, will the script also delete an unsupported arch from it?

Comment: @HarshalWani if supporting framework is just a dependency for your framework, then it'll be linked to app separately and archs will be deleted. Else if it's included in your framework's binary, I suppose it's slices are merged with your framework's slices, and so they'll be deleted while processing your framework; but can't say for sure, better if you check your binaries after processing.

Comment: Getting the error "fatal error: lipo: input file... must be a fat file when the -remove option is specified" which leads to "ERROR ITMS-90085: "No architectures in the binary. Lipo failed to detect any architectures in the bundle executable.""

Comment: The error was caused because the library I used had two framework files, one built for the simulator and one for devices.

Answer (score 91):

If you're using [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage) then you may experience this issue because the project is:

- Missing the `carthage copy-frameworks` build phase.
- Or the build phase doesn't include all the frameworks (incomplete list).

This action filters frameworks to a list of valid architectures [(code)](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/blob/b91bd46b3437fbe03d8b3560c3938baeb788958f/Source/carthage/CopyFrameworks.swift#L51).

#### Setting up the copy-frameworks build phase

From the [Carthage building for iOS steps](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage#if-youre-building-for-ios-tvos-or-watchos):

> On your application targets’ “Build Phases” settings tab, click the
>   “+” icon and choose “New Run Script Phase”. Create a Run Script in
>   which you specify your shell (ex: bin/sh), add the following contents
>   to the script area below the shell:
>
> `/usr/local/bin/carthage copy-frameworks`
>
> and add the paths to the frameworks you want to use under “Input Files”, e.g.:
>
> `$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/Box.framework`
>   `$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/Result.framework` 
>   `$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/ReactiveCocoa.framework`
>
> This script works around an App Store submission bug triggered by universal
>   binaries and ensures that necessary bitcode-related files and dSYMs
>   are copied when archiving.

Comment: As an additional note, I recently ran into this problem having switched from using an old, pre-compiled version of a third-party framework to a new version of the same framework installed using Carthage. Even once Carthage was fully set up I continued to get this error. For me, the fix was to entirely remove the framework from the project and add it back again. If you're using Carthage and this answer doesn't fix it for you, try doing that.

Comment: Indeed, a great post.  Note, often your best bet is simply remove all frameworks, and start again adding all your frameworks from Carthage.  Cheers

Comment: I'm using Carthage and Marshal and adding `$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/Marshal.framework` did the work

Comment: in modern iOS, 99% of the time this is the problem - you just forgot the copy-frameworks.  (100% of projects now use Carthage.)

Answer (score 42):

I resolved the error ITMS-90080 by removing a framework (the excellent SVProgressHUD) from the Embedded Binaries section (Xcode target -> General tab).

[image]

Comment: This answer should have many more upvotes. I suspect it's the root cause for many people using Carthage.

Comment: If you're trying to embed a dynamic framework then removing it results in this error message for me: "Reason: image not found"

Comment: This worked for me. You have to remove the framework from Embedded Binaries and just add it to the Linked Frameworks and Libraries. Also, you have to do the other stuff like running the script that you find in the other answers.

Answer (score 34):

If you are using `Carthage` make sure your `Embed Frameworks` `Build Step` is before the `Carthage` `copy-frameworks`

---

In some unusual cases (example: Lottie-iOS framework):

- you will have it simply in "Link Library" as usual.
- **However** you have to **also** explicitly add it in "Embed Frameworks" (even though that seems pointless, since it works perfectly when you have it only in "Embed Frameworks"),
- *and* put it in copy-frameworks
- *and* ensure copy-frameworks is **after** "Embed Frameworks"

Comment: This way my issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 21):

Remove **[x86_64, i386]** from the framework using below step. **[x86_64, i386]** is used for simulator.

1. Open `Terminal`
2. open your project drag path of respective framework to Terminal

   example : `cd /Users/MAC/Desktop/MyProject/Alamofire.framework`
3. set your Framework name in below command and run

`lipo -remove i386 Alamofire -o Alamofire && lipo -remove x86_64 Alamofire -o Alamofire`

4. Now open your project again, Clean, Build & Run and Create Archive...

Comment: @mahipal Singh ..  after removing using lipo command.  app is not working in simulator. got error like x84_64 missing for iphone simulator.   but working fine in real device.

Comment: It's because simulator support only debug framework

Comment: This works for any downloaded framework, just renaming `Alamofire` with the framework you're having trouble with. Thanks for this answer.

Answer (score 16):

I will add my 2 cents here (in a less scary way :-). I have encountered quite a number of fat libraries from Vendors that (for some reason) do not work the normal way by adding them to the `Frameworks` directory as documented by Apple. The only way we have been able to make them work is by pulling the `.framekwork` right into the project directory and linking the `Embedded Frameworks` and `Link Binary with Libraries` manually in Build Settings. This seem to have worked without any issues, however, as with any fat library they come with the extraneous Simulator Architectures `i386`  and `x86_64` along with the `arm` architectures.

A quick way to check the architectures on the fat library is

```
$ cd 'Project_dir/Project'
$ lipo -info 'YourLibrary.framework/YourLibExec`
```

Which should spit an output something like this

```
Architectures in the fat file: YourLibrary.framework/YourLibExec are: i386 x86_64 armv7 arm64
```

This confirms that you will need to "trim the fat" (namely `i386` & `x86_64`) from your framework prior to iTunesConnect Archival upload, which doesn't allow these architectures (since they are unsupported for iOS).

Now, all the answers (or atleast some of the answers) here provide these wonderful Run Scripts that I am sure works really well, but only if your Framework resides in the `Frameworks` directory. Now unless you are a shell script junkie, those scripts without modifications, won't work for the scenario I explain above. However, there is a very simple way to get rid of the `i386` & `x86_64` architectures from the framework.

1. Open terminal in your project's directory.
2. Change directory directly into the `.framekwork`, like

   `cd YourProjectDir/YourProject/YourLibrary.framework`
3. Run the series of commands as shown below-

```sh
$ mv YourLibrary YourLibrary_all_archs
$ lipo -remove x86_64 YourLibrary_all_archs -o YourLibrary_some_archs
$ lipo -remove i386 YourLibrary_some_archs -o YourLibrary
$ rm YourLibrary_all_archs YourLibrary_some_archs
```

A few things to note here - `lipo -remove` has to be done once for each architecture to remove. `lipo` does not modify the input file, it only produces a file so you have to run `lipo -remove` once for `x86_64` and `i386`. The commands above is simply doing that by first renaming the executable and then eventually removing the desired archs, and then cleaning up the left over files. And that's it, you should now see a green check mark in Application Loader Archival upload to iTunesConnect.

**Things to keep in mind** : The above steps should only be done while production build, since the `.framework` will be stripped off the simulator architectures, builds on simulators will stop working (which is expected). In development environment, there should be no need to strip the architectures off of the `.framework` file since you want to be able to test on both Simulator and a physical device. If your fat library resides in the `Frameworks` folder in the project then please look at the accepted answer.

Comment: Simple solution for those that don't feel like scripting.

Comment: just run the command above, the arch size reduced to half. hopefully make some difference.

Comment: Even though i have deployed the script to make everything work as normal but this has to be a proper description on how to resolve the issue.

Comment: love the nature of this answer. clean and concise

Answer (score 16):

Thanks to all the above answers. Here is a script working with **swift 4.2 and 5**. Replace Your_Framework_Name string with your Framework's original name.

```
APP_PATH="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}"
FRAMEWORK_NAME="Your_Framework_Name.framework"
# Check if Framework is present.
FRAMEWORK_LOCATION=$(find "$APP_PATH" -name "$FRAMEWORK_NAME" -type d)
if [ -z $FRAMEWORK_LOCATION ]; then
echo "Couldn't find Your_Framework_Name.framework in $APP_PATH. Make sure 'Embed Frameworks' build phase is listed before the 'Strip Unused Architectures' build phase."
exit 1
fi
# This script strips unused architectures
find "$APP_PATH" -name "$FRAMEWORK_NAME" -type d | while read -r FRAMEWORK
do
FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME=$(defaults read "$FRAMEWORK/Info.plist" CFBundleExecutable)
FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH="$FRAMEWORK/$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
echo "Executable is $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
EXTRACTED_ARCHS=()
for ARCH in $ARCHS
do
echo "Extracting $ARCH from $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
lipo -extract "$ARCH" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH"
EXTRACTED_ARCHS+=("$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH")
done
echo "Merging extracted architectures: ${ARCHS}"
lipo -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" -create "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"
rm "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"
echo "Replacing original executable with thinned version"
rm "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
mv "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
done
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me, while the accepted answer did not.

Answer (score 14):

I had same issue even after adding the script and updating the framework a few times.

**Make sure in xCode the script is added at the end, after the embed**. I think I accidentally moved the script before the embedded framework.

[image]

Note: I have xCode 9.1

Comment: This worked for me.  Where just @pAkY88's script was enough last time i did a release nearly a year ago.

Comment: I had the same issue and this worked for me. Make sure to check the position of the run script every time a framework is removed and added (only necessary when there is only one framework that was removed).

Comment: You save my day. Just to add script after embedded framework.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me, just add this scrip at the end of all scripts

Answer (score 9):

> Updated for Xcode 10.1, Below solution worked for me :

Just you have to remove the framework from Embedded Binaries and just add it to the Linked Frameworks and Libraries.

Refer below screenshot;

[image]

Comment: Working solution for me (y)

Comment: it removes the same from linked frameworks and libraries

Answer (score 6):

This issue was resolved for me by slightly modifying the run script from pAky88's answer and executing after embedding frameworks.  Also be sure to uncheck the box for "Run Script only when installing".

```
/usr/local/bin/carthage copy-frameworks

#!/usr/bin/env bash

APP_PATH="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}"

# This script loops through the frameworks embedded in the application and
# removes unused architectures.
find "$APP_PATH" -name '*.framework' -type d | while read -r FRAMEWORK
do
FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME=$(defaults read "$FRAMEWORK/Info.plist" CFBundleExecutable)
FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH="$FRAMEWORK/$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"

if [ ! -f "${FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH}" ]; then
continue
fi

if xcrun lipo -info "${FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH}" | grep --silent "Non-fat"; then
echo "Framework non-fat, skipping: $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
continue
fi

echo "Thinning framework $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"

EXTRACTED_ARCHS=()

for ARCH in $ARCHS
do
echo "Extracting $ARCH from $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
xcrun lipo -extract "$ARCH" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH"
EXTRACTED_ARCHS+=("$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH")
done

echo "Merging extracted architectures: ${ARCHS}"
xcrun lipo -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" -create "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"
rm "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"

echo "Replacing original executable with thinned version"
rm "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
mv "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
done
```

Answer (score 5):

I removed architectures i386 & x64_86 from Build Settings - Valid Architectures - Release, and everything worked just fine.

[image]

Now the only issue would be that you can't run a **RELEASE** build for testing purposes on a **SIMULATOR**. But as easily as you removed the archs, you can add them back if you want to.

Comment: YES, that the solution.

Answer (score 3):

the simple solution that worked for me was

> 1- remove the framework from embedded frameworks.
>
> 2- add the framework as a linked framework

done!

Answer (score 1):

This error (ITMS-90240) can also be caused by a static (.a) library. heres a script to strip the excess architectures. In Xcode add this to Target > BuildPhases > Click the + and select Run Script. Then paste this into the script box.

The script searches for .a files, checks to see if it contains an offending architecture, then if it does makes a new .a file without that architecture.

For macOS:

```
APP_PATH="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}"
STRIPARCHS="armv7 armv7s arm64"
for t in $STRIPARCHS
do

if find "$APP_PATH" -name '*.a' -exec lipo -info {} \; | grep $t ; then
    find "$APP_PATH" -name '*.a' -exec lipo -remove $t {} -output {}2 \; -exec rm {} \; -exec mv {}2 {} \; ;
fi

done

exit 0
```

For iOS :

```
APP_PATH="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}"
STRIPARCHS="x86_64 i386"
for t in $STRIPARCHS
do

if find "$APP_PATH" -name '*.a' -exec lipo -info {} \; | grep $t ; then
    find "$APP_PATH" -name '*.a' -exec lipo -remove $t {} -output {}2 \; -exec rm {} \; -exec mv {}2 {} \; ;
fi

done

exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue.
Even it was not working after adding the given Run Script.
It was Xcode related issue.
I was using the Xcode version 9.0 but latest version was 9.2.

So i installed latest Xcode (9.2) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your framework contains both `ARM` and `x86` code, which allows you to use it on a device or in the simulator. If you intend to submit your app to the App Store, run the following script to strip the inactive code from the binary.

1.Select your target in the Project Navigator, and click Build Phases at the top of the project editor.

2.From the Editor menu, select Add Build Phase, then Add Run Script Build Phase (or click the + button in the upper-left corner of the Build Phases editor).

3.Expand the disclosure triangle next to the new Run Script build phase that was just added. In the script editor box, paste the following:
bash

> ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/**"YourframeworkName.framework"**/strip-frameworks.sh

Comment: This assumes that the strip-frameworks.sh script happens to be there...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script I used to specifically remove just one framework's architecture from the executable file.

```sh
# Remove unused Framework architecture from "YourApp" framework.

FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}/Frameworks/YourApp.framework/YourApp"

echo "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

cp "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" "${FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH}_X86_64"

echo "Executing following command to remove x86_64 arch from YourApp framework executable"
echo "lipo -remove x86_64 \"$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH\" -o \"${FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH}_X86_64\""

lipo -remove x86_64 "${FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH}_X86_64" -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

rm "${FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH}_X86_64"
```

Add this script to your projects "Build Phases" of your project target. Be sure to check the box: "Run script only when installing"

[image: Preview of where to insert sample script]