# AWS Framework and XCode Conundrum

Tags: xcode, swift, amazon-web-services, app-store, aws-sdk

I am trying to upload an XCode project to App Store and running into frameworks related issues. The project has AWSCore framework, which rather than cocoa pods route, has been manually downloaded and added to the project. It also has been added to both the 'Build Phases' settings of target - 'Embedded Binaries' and 'Linked Frameworks and Libraries'. These two setting combined however, might be causing the below mentioned issues while uploading the project to App Store:

ERROR ITMS-90087: "Unsupported Architectures. The executable for /Frameworks/AWSCore.framework contains unsupported architectures '[x86_64, i386]’."

ERROR ITMS-90209: "Invalid Segment Alignment. /Frameworks/AWSCore.framework/AWSCore' does not have proper segment alignment. Try rebuilding the app with the latest Xcode version."

I do have the latest version of XCode, so not sure why I am getting the second error message. Some StackOverflow posts suggested removing  the framework from 'Embedded Binaries' section of 'Build Phases', but that's introducing the following run time error:

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/AWSCore.framework/AWSCore Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/

This seems to be quite a conundrum. Wondering if anyone else has run into same issue and what has been the fix? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the similar question!

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by William GP in the comments to the question, my question was similar to the one asked here: [Submit to App Store issues: Unsupported Architecture x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547283/submit-to-app-store-issues).

Please see the following link for the perfectly well described analysis of the problem and also detailed solution by Daniel Kennett: http://ikennd.ac/blog/2015/02/stripping-unwanted-architectures-from-dynamic-libraries-in-xcode/