# XCODE: Submit to App Store issues

Tags: xcode

When i archive the app and validate it then there are no issues but when i submit it to the app store then it gives me the following issues.

```
ERROR ITMS-90087: "Unsupported Architectures. The executable for Bai Chat.app/Frameworks/RelatedSDK.framework contains unsupported architectures '[x86_64]'."


ERROR ITMS-90209: "Invalid Segment Alignment. The app binary at 'Bai Chat.app/Frameworks/RelatedSDK.framework/RelatedSDK' does not have proper segment alignment. Try rebuilding the app with the latest Xcode version."


ERROR ITMS-90125: "The binary is invalid. The encryption info in the LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO load command is either missing or invalid, or the binary is already encrypted. This binary does not seem to have been built with Apple's linker."

WARNING ITMS-90080: "The executable 'Payload/Bai Chat.app/Frameworks/RelatedSDK.framework' is not a Position Independent Executable. Please ensure that your build settings are configured to create PIE executables. For more information refer to Technical Q&A QA1788 - Building a Position Independent Executable in the iOS Developer Library."
```

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqDL4.png)

Any idea how to solve one of these error

Thank you.

Comment: Well, you have AppStore log with error codes, so try to Google each error code for solution, try to implement solution, and ask for help again if any required.

Comment: Also take a look at this thread - it seems to be what you want, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547283/submit-to-app-store-issues