# Framework contains unsupported architectures Xcode 8

Tags: xcode, architecture, app-store, xcode8

I'm getting this error when trying to validate my app archive.

> iTunes Store operation failed.
>   Unsupported Architectures. The executable for .../Frameworks/ImageSlideshow.framework contains unsupported architectures '[x86_64, i386]'.

I've tried to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547283/submit-to-app-store-issues) solution, but complier give me 20 errors if I build with that script. I've understood that I need to change something (that the script should do automatically). Can I do it manually?

What should I do?

Thank you guys

PS. I've installed "ImageSlideshow" with Cocoapods (I don't know if it's relevant).

Answer (score 1):

## SOLUTION

In this///// post there's a general script, that modify all frameworks in project, but I need that only 1 framework should be modified (because is the only that give me error).

So, you need to change that script from (line 5):

```
find "$APP_PATH" -name '*.framework' -type d | while read -r FRAMEWORK
```

to:

```
find "$APP_PATH" -name '<ENTER FRAMEWORK NAME>.framework' -type d | while read -r FRAMEWORK
```

let's build! It's time to upload it on AppStore!