# Google Cast iOS SDK v3.3 archive upload issue

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, google-cast

I use latest version of **Xcode** (8.2.1 b8C1002) and latest version of **GoogleCast.framework** (3.3.0)

Obviously i followed [these steps](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender_setup#xcode_setup) to integrate the SDK

When i try to upload my archived application i found these issues

[image]

someone had this trouble and found a solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Solved my issue with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30866648/1197966)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iOS Sender v3.3 added a shell script strip_unused_archs.sh to the SDK package that strips unused architectures from an app bundle. This enables submitting to the App Store. For example, this script removes simulator slices, which are included in the framework but are not allowed in the App Store.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just to be clear, I have to add new "Run Script Phase" under "Project Settings -> Build Phases" ?

Comment: Where I am supposed to add execution of the script `strip_unused_archs.sh`? Is it really necessary? I successfully uploaded the app with Google Cast SDK 3.3.0 _without_ adding a run script phase for this script.

Comment: PS: The documentation could be clearer about this, where the execution of this script should be added. Xcode has different settings where post script execution is possible: "Scheme Management" with "Post Actions" and also project settings with "Run Script" actions in "Build Phases".

Comment: So where do you use this script? I tried it as a normal run script in build phases and as a post-build script in my scheme, but I got the still got the ERROR ITMS..

Comment: Please guide, where & how to add this script! Tried adding in build phase/runscript but facing errors

Comment: How big should the built framework be? I installed with Cocoapods, and it's around 650MB https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53465950/why-is-chromecast-sdk-for-ios-with-so-big-when-installed-with-cocoapods

Answer (score 5):

Add `strip_unused_archs.sh` In Project -> Build Phases -> New Run Script Phase

[image: Build Phases]

`strip_unused_archs.sh` will scan entire your project's framework path to create new frameworks that are only built for your current target. If you build for simulator, you will only get x86_64 slice. If you build for real devices or "Generic iOS devices," you get arm64. If your app support older devices, other older archs (e.q. armv7) remain.

Note that not only does GoogleCast framework get stripped, all frameworks under Framework Search Path do.

Comment: Thanks @Benson, the script somehow conflicts with the Carthage copy-frameworks script :/

Comment: @fruitcoder The order in Build Phases matters. I run `strip_unused_archs.sh` after `carthage copy-framework`, and there is no problem to submit to appStore.

Comment: This just doens't work for me.. The script is executed but I get the same errors

Comment: @ fruitcoder Could you please move this script to Scheme -> Build -> Post-actions? It should be the last step on all builds complete.