# How to strip Google cast unused archs iOS | strip_unused_archs.sh

Tags: ios, xcode, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I've integrated Google cast support in my iOS app using official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender_setup) and cocoapods. It's mentioned that before publishing app, you need to run shell script strip_unused_archs.sh to strip unused architectures from the app bundle.

I've tried adding script in buildphase/runphase section but it's not working. I'm facing the issue while locating the script. However i can locate it if i use cast SDK manually (without pods)

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41568266/google-cast-ios-sdk-v3-3-archive-upload-issue) stackover flow thread, but no help as i'm not able to locate the script in my project.

How to run this script when you're using cocoapods?

Answer (score 1):

If you have added Google cast using cocoapods, you don't have to strip any symbols.
If you've added it manually, then you must add the script to remove them.

Comment: Approximately how big is the GoogleCast.framework supposed to me? I installed with Cocoapods and the framework is around 650MB, which seems too big. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53465950/why-is-chromecast-sdk-for-ios-with-so-big-when-installed-with-cocoapods