# Why is Chromecast SDK for iOS so big when installed with Cocoapods?

Tags: ios, chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I recently added the Chromecast SDK to my project, and `GoogleCast.framework` is nearly **650MB**.

Is that the normal size? If not, how can I decrease the size?

I installed it with Cocoapods (the `google-cast-sdk` pod) and my project is all in Swift.

Comment: Usually the size of IOS Chromecast SDK is over 300 MB. That's a normal size. You can read more info in [Making libraries for React Native](https://medium.com/gbox-crew-blog/making-libraries-for-react-native-eaca35b5b1d7).