# input file XXXX must be a fat file when the -remove option is specified

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight, fastlane, lipo

I am trying to publish our app to testflight/appstore by fastlane and i get these two errors:

1. > fatal error: lipo: input file (==FILEPATH==/CommonCrypto.framework/CommonCrypto) must be a fat file when the -remove option is specified
2. > fatal error: lipo: can't open input file: ==FILEPATH==/Frameworks/CommonCrypto.framework/CommonCrypto (No such file or directory)

---

Before i got these errors i got lot of "Unsupported Architectures" errors.

> ERROR ITMS-90087: "Unsupported Architectures. The executable for ==APPNAME==.app/Frameworks/==FRAMEWORK_NAME==.framework contains unsupported
>   architectures '[x86_64, i386]'."
>
> ERROR ITMS-90087: "Unsupported Architectures. The executable for ==APPNAME==.app/Frameworks/CommonCrypto.framework contains unsupported
>   architectures '[x86_64]'."

So i added this script to the build phase:[(From another stack overflow post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547283/submit-to-app-store-issues-unsupported-architecture-x86?answertab=votes#tab-top)

```
APP_PATH="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}"

# This script loops through the frameworks embedded in the application and
# removes unused architectures.
find "$APP_PATH" -name '*.framework' -type d | while read -r FRAMEWORK
do
    FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME=$(defaults read "$FRAMEWORK/Info.plist" CFBundleExecutable)
    FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH="$FRAMEWORK/$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
    echo "Executable is $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

    EXTRACTED_ARCHS=()

    for ARCH in $ARCHS
    do
        echo "Extracting $ARCH from $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
        lipo -extract "$ARCH" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH"
        EXTRACTED_ARCHS+=("$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH")
    done

    echo "Merging extracted architectures: ${ARCHS}"
    lipo -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" -create "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"
    rm "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"

    echo "Replacing original executable with thinned version"
    rm "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
    mv "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"

done
```

---

### Build settings:

- **Architectures:** Standard Architectures
- **Base SDK:** iOS 11.0
- **Build Active Architectures Only:** YES (tried with NO)
- **Supported Platforms:** iOS
- **Valid Architectures:** arm64, arm7, arm7s

---

### NOTE

The **commoncrypto** framework is added manualy in embedded Binaries since its only avalible through Carthage. But the project uses mainly cocoapods.

---

I guess removing the script would solve it. But then its back to the old problem.

But all help is appreciated!

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: Its a while now, and I don't work on this project anymore, so I don't remember. Sorry.

Comment: @PankajWadhwa if you're still facing issues, I recommend you opening an Issue in fastlane official repository to get support faster :)