# Alamofire Framework

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm using `Alamofire` in my project and everything go find when i run the project in my **IPhone 5s**, but i have another **IPhone 5** and when I run the application I got this error

> lipo: input file
>   (../myApp.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire) must be a fat
>   file when the -delete option is specified.

i'm using **swift 4.0**

I tried many solutions but nothing work such as include an script i found in this post

[input file XXXX must be a fat file when the -remove option is specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46422922/input-file-xxxx-must-be-a-fat-file-when-the-remove-option-is-specified)

Any help?

thank you

Comment: How did you integrate it into your project? I'd recommend the manual method: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Comment: using the pod file,     pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.5'

Comment: it's works using the manual method..!! thank you!!!!

Comment: I write it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually [add](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#installation) it to your project:

If you prefer not to use any of the aforementioned dependency managers, you can integrate Alamofire into your project manually.

**Embedded Framework**

- Open up Terminal, `cd` into your top-level project directory, and run the following command "if" your project is not initialized as a git repository:

  `$ git init`
- Add Alamofire as a git [submodule](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) by running the following command:

  `$ git submodule add https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git`
- Open the new `Alamofire` folder, and drag the `Alamofire.xcodeproj` into the Project Navigator of your application's Xcode project.

  > It should appear nested underneath your application's blue project icon. Whether it is above or below all the other Xcode groups does not matter.
- Select the `Alamofire.xcodeproj` in the Project Navigator and verify the deployment target matches that of your application target.
- Next, select your application project in the Project Navigator (blue project icon) to navigate to the target configuration window and select the application target under the "Targets" heading in the sidebar.
- In the tab bar at the top of that window, open the "General" panel.
- Click on the `+` button under the "Embedded Binaries" section.
- You will see two different `Alamofire.xcodeproj` folders each with two different versions of the `Alamofire.framework` nested inside a `Products` folder.

  > It does not matter which `Products` folder you choose from, but it does matter whether you choose the top or bottom `Alamofire.framework`.
- Select the top `Alamofire.framework` for iOS and the bottom one for OS X.

  > You can verify which one you selected by inspecting the build log for your project. The build target for `Alamofire` will be listed as either `Alamofire iOS`, `Alamofire macOS`, `Alamofire tvOS` or `Alamofire watchOS`.
- And that's it!

  > The `Alamofire.framework` is automagically added as a target dependency, linked framework and embedded framework in a copy files build phase which is all you need to build on the simulator and a device.

Comment: it was about adding alamofire, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: I mean to say how to add ALAMOFIRE FRAMEWORK in a custom FRAMEWORK?

Comment: @AlizainPrasla  I don't know about creating frameworks.