# Xcode Unsupported Architectures occurred errors when I send to iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, app-store-connect

iTunes Connect gives this kind of error:

iTunes Store Operation Failed
ERROR ITMS-90087: "Unsupported Architectures. The executable for FlowTestFram.app/Frameworks/My.framework contains unsupported architectures '[x86_64, i386]'."

iTunes Store Operation Failed
ERROR ITMS-90635: "Invalid Mach-O Format. The Mach-O in bundle "FlowTestFram.app/Frameworks/My.framework" isn’t consistent with the Mach-O in the main bundle. The main bundle Mach-O contains armv7(bitcode) and arm64(bitcode), while the nested bundle Mach-O contains X86_64ALL(machine code). Verify that all of the targets for a platform have a consistent value for the ENABLE_BITCODE build setting."

iTunes Store Operation Failed
ERROR ITMS-90209: "Invalid Segment Alignment. The app binary at 'FlowTestFram.app/Frameworks/My.framework/my' does not have proper segment alignment. Try rebuilding the app with the latest Xcode version."

iTunes Store Operation Failed
ERROR ITMS-90125: "The binary is invalid. The encryption info in the LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO load command is either missing or invalid, or the binary is already encrypted. This binary does not seem to have been built with Apple's linker."

I use standard architectures: arm64, armv7, armv7s

Can anybody help me out for this?

Thanks!

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547283/submit-to-app-store-issues-unsupported-architecture-x86