# Shell script for remove the unneeded architectures while archiving not working

Tags: ios, xcode, shell

I have tried to use the shell scripts of [@Varrry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5272316/varrry) and [@pAkY88](https://stackoverflow.com/users/343201/paky88) on the question [Submit to App Store issues: Unsupported Architecture x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547283/submit-to-app-store-issues-unsupported-architecture-x86/41416964#comment81773958_41416964) but they are not working while archiving,the unneeded architectures are not removed, so when I'm trying to upload to the Store I get the error: "Unsupported Architecture. Your executable contains unsupported architecture '[x86_64, i386]'."

The project (Swift) has arm64 armv7 and armv7s as valid architectures, the project is using a framework made by myself(in Swift), and some firebase frameworks(Objective-C), all this frameworks have the simulator slice because I'm using a continues integration and all the tests runs on the simulator.

The log from the script is [here](https://justpaste.it/1dq7d)

Comment: Have you tried to check archive's binary manually? What the archs there were?

Comment: Or maybe you didn't run the script in a correct order? That script must be run in Build Phases after the Embed Frameworks.

Comment: Thanks you that was the error. The script was before the Embed Frameworks, now the archiving and CI, are working correctly.