# Crash symbolicated but unable to resolve. App Store reject binary

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, skmaps, symbolicatecrash

I have developed a basic iOS app using objective C. Less than 300 lines of code. 
The app runs great on all iPhone simulators and on my iPhone, I've sent the app to apple for uploading to the App Store and they've rejecting it as it crashes. They sent me the .txt which I've converted to symbolicated crash logs and of which it reads the following, a very, very long crash log which I cannot understand:

```
    {"app_name":"Speedometer","timestamp":"2018-03-02 12:13:04.86 -0800","app_version":"1.1","slice_uuid":"0f723e67-c82d-3204-af69-3283896f7709","adam_id":1352122570,"build_version":"2","bundleID":"ManeshApps.Speedometer","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 11.2.6 (15D100)","incident_id":"A24F40D1-EEFF-4135-B8A6-8D5AD5370BAA","name":"Speedometer"}
Incident Identifier: A24F40D1-EEFF-4135-B8A6-8D5AD5370BAA
CrashReporter Key:   19fa742cda356e0d010486f2a3f39666d72e2728
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             Speedometer [4778]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/85553CB7-6F92-4DDD-A6D2-52591E2084AA/Speedometer.app/Speedometer
Identifier:          ManeshApps.Speedometer
Version:             2 (1.1)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           ManeshApps.Speedometer [873]


Date/Time:           2018-03-02 12:13:04.4872 -0800
Launch Time:         2018-03-02 12:13:03.6027 -0800
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.2.6 (15D100)
Baseband Version:    
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
___exceptionPreprocess + 124
_objc_exception_throw + 56
+[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 104
-[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 112
-[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 2908
___111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 800
+[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 160
-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 252
-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 732
___82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 260
-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 448
___125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 220
__performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 112
-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 252
-[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 364
-[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 540
-[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 364
-[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 364
___56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 224
__dispatch_client_callout + 16
__dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 288
___FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36
-[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 404
-[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
___CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
___CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 88
___CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 204
___CFRunLoopRun + 1048
_CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
_GSEventRunModal + 100
_UIApplicationMain + 236
_main main.m:14
_start + 4


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
___pthread_kill + 8
_pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 396
_abort + 140
_abort_message + 132
default_terminate_handler() + 304
_objc_terminate() + 124
std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
std::terminate() + 60
__dispatch_client_callout + 36
__dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 288
___FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36
-[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 404
-[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
___CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
___CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 88
___CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 204
___CFRunLoopRun + 1048
_CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
_GSEventRunModal + 100
_UIApplicationMain + 236
_main main.m:14
_start + 4

Thread 1:
_pthread_workqueue_addthreads_np + 124

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.CoreLocation.ConnectionClient.0x1c0133b00.events
Thread 2:
_semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
__dispatch_sema4_timedwait$VARIANT$mp + 84
__dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 72
_CLClientInvalidate + 652
_CLClientRetrieveData + 1680
_CLClientRetrieveData + 960
_CLClientCreateIso6709Notation + 76952
_CLClientCreateIso6709Notation + 61548
_CLClientCreateIso6709Notation + 61328
_CLClientCreateIso6709Notation + 67620
__xpc_connection_call_event_handler + 68
__xpc_connection_mach_event + 984
__dispatch_client_callout4 + 16
__dispatch_mach_msg_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 356
__dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 200
__dispatch_mach_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 952
__dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 200
__dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 340
__dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 200
__dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 340
__dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh$VARIANT$mp + 404
__dispatch_workloop_worker_thread$VARIANT$mp + 644
__pthread_wqthread + 932
_start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3:
_pthread_workqueue_addthreads_np + 124

Thread 4:
_pthread_workqueue_addthreads_np + 124

Thread 5:
_pthread_workqueue_addthreads_np + 124

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 6:
_mach_msg_trap + 8
_mach_msg + 72
___CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
___CFRunLoopRun + 1424
_CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
-[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96
-[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
___NSThread__start__ + 996
__pthread_body + 308
__pthread_start + 312
_thread_start + 4

Thread 7:
___psynch_cvwait + 8
__pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 640
2   SKMaps                          0x00000001016eef2c 0x101498000 + 2453292
3   SKMaps                          0x00000001016eb71c 0x101498000 + 2438940
__pthread_body + 308
__pthread_start + 312
_thread_start + 4

Thread 8 name:  MapMatcher
Thread 8:
___psynch_cvwait + 8
__pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 696
2   SKMaps                          0x000000010168e9d0 0x101498000 + 2058704
__pthread_body + 308
__pthread_start + 312
_thread_start + 4

Thread 9 name:  RendererWorker
Thread 9:
___psynch_cvwait + 8
__pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 640
2   SKMaps                          0x000000010169c00c 0x101498000 + 2113548
3   SKMaps                          0x00000001016e4b84 0x101498000 + 2411396
__pthread_body + 308
__pthread_start + 312
_thread_start + 4

Thread 10:
___psynch_cvwait + 8
__pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 640
2   SKMaps                          0x0000000101543f68 0x101498000 + 704360
3   SKMaps                          0x000000010152994c 0x101498000 + 596300
__pthread_body + 308
__pthread_start + 312
_thread_start + 4

Thread 11 name:  ReRenderTimer
Thread 11:
___psynch_cvwait + 8
__pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 696
2   SKMaps                          0x0000000101525ec4 0x101498000 + 581316
__pthread_body + 308
__pthread_start + 312
_thread_start + 4

Thread 12 name:  AnimationTimer
Thread 12:
___psynch_cvwait + 8
__pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 696
2   SKMaps                          0x0000000101525f8c 0x101498000 + 581516
__pthread_body + 308
__pthread_start + 312
_thread_start + 4

Thread 13:
___psynch_cvwait + 8
__pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 640
2   SKMaps                          0x00000001015f0564 0x101498000 + 1410404
__pthread_body + 308
__pthread_start + 312
_thread_start + 4

Thread 14:
___psynch_cvwait + 8
__pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 640
2   SKMaps                          0x00000001015ff2d8 0x101498000 + 1471192
__pthread_body + 308
__pthread_start + 312
_thread_start + 4

Thread 15:
___psynch_cvwait + 8
__pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 640
2   SKMaps                          0x00000001016a31a8 0x101498000 + 2142632
3   SKMaps                          0x00000001016a3124 0x101498000 + 2142500
__pthread_body + 308
__pthread_start + 312
_thread_start + 4

Thread 16 name:  FcdCollector
Thread 16:
___psynch_cvwait + 8
__pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 696
2   SKMaps                          0x0000000101670e84 0x101498000 + 1937028
__pthread_body + 308
__pthread_start + 312
_thread_start + 4

Thread 17:
___psynch_cvwait + 8
__pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 640
2   SKMaps                          0x000000010173f650 0x101498000 + 2782800
3   SKMaps                          0x000000010174010c 0x101498000 + 2785548
4   SKMaps                          0x0000000101740290 0x101498000 + 2785936
__pthread_body + 308
__pthread_start + 312
_thread_start + 4

Thread 18:
___psynch_cvwait + 8
__pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 640
2   SKMaps                          0x000000010173f650 0x101498000 + 2782800
3   SKMaps                          0x000000010174010c 0x101498000 + 2785548
4   SKMaps                          0x0000000101740290 0x101498000 + 2785936
__pthread_body + 308
__pthread_start + 312
_thread_start + 4

Thread 19:
_kevent + 8
__mdns_search + 2020
_mdns_addrinfo + 940
_search_addrinfo + 264
_si_addrinfo + 1672
__getaddrinfo_internal + 196
_getaddrinfo + 56
7   SKMaps                          0x000000010174300c 0x101498000 + 2797580
8   SKMaps                          0x0000000101742e50 0x101498000 + 2797136
9   SKMaps                          0x0000000101741708 0x101498000 + 2791176
10  SKMaps                          0x0000000101740d34 0x101498000 + 2788660
11  SKMaps                          0x0000000101740ca0 0x101498000 + 2788512
12  SKMaps                          0x000000010158d390 0x101498000 + 1004432
13  SKMaps                          0x00000001016e4d98 0x101498000 + 2411928
14  SKMaps                          0x00000001016e4b84 0x101498000 + 2411396
__pthread_body + 308
__pthread_start + 312
_thread_start + 4

Thread 20:
___semwait_signal + 8
_nanosleep + 212
_sleep + 44
3   SKMaps                          0x00000001016e4bb0 0x101498000 + 2411440
4   SKMaps                          0x00000001016e4b84 0x101498000 + 2411396
__pthread_body + 308
__pthread_start + 312
_thread_start + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x00000001c80fe737
    x4: 0x0000000185cbcafd   x5: 0x000000016eb16580   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x00000001866ad5e0  x11: 0x0000000000000003
   x12: 0xffffffffffffffff  x13: 0x0000000000000001  x14: 0x000000018651953f  x15: 0x0000000000000010
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x00000000ffffffff  x18: 0xfffffff01c29925c  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x00000001b78e4b80  x21: 0x000000016eb16580  x22: 0x0000000000000303  x23: 0x00000001b78e4c60
   x24: 0x0000000000001f03  x25: 0x0000000000001c03  x26: 0x0000000000000001  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x00000001c81e4808   fp: 0x000000016eb164e0   lr: 0x00000001866a92f8
    sp: 0x000000016eb164b0   pc: 0x00000001865942e8 cpsr: 0x00000000

Binary Images:
0x1012e8000 - 0x1012f3fff Speedometer arm64  <0f723e67c82d3204af693283896f7709> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/85553CB7-6F92-4DDD-A6D2-52591E2084AA/Speedometer.app/Speedometer
0x1013fc000 - 0x10143bfff dyld arm64  <477a8a1f098b3a80860d656a3f4918ea> /usr/lib/dyld
0x101498000 - 0x1018e7fff SKMaps arm64  <d3aaf7ab39ec3f14901a66306997a8b0> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/85553CB7-6F92-4DDD-A6D2-52591E2084AA/Speedometer.app/Frameworks/SKMaps.framework/SKMaps
0x185c41000 - 0x185c42fff libSystem.B.dylib arm64  <a9f67ca8b7963c699078236267472fb0> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x185c43000 - 0x185c9cfff libc++.1.dylib arm64  <aee157a049663aa88c4e928768cfd553> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x185c9d000 - 0x185cbdfff libc++abi.dylib arm64  <b4f54419327f3bfea747549b84dad328> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x185cc0000 - 0x18637bfff libobjc.A.dylib arm64  <3a9d464322eb3285bc88fabf7cec20ed> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x18637c000 - 0x186380fff libcache.dylib arm64  <474a695498903419b648b834067fac4e> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x186381000 - 0x18638cfff libcommonCrypto.dylib arm64  <f3a95fbdb7a037879160ae9e0ee14c37> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x18638d000 - 0x186390fff libcompiler_rt.dylib arm64  <502de73c3e0c3ba78280e6164fe5728c> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x186391000 - 0x186398fff libcopyfile.dylib arm64  <b8c962560a1b3b639d562541d32f5960> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x186399000 - 0x1863fcfff libcorecrypto.dylib arm64  <db41a416fa083812bcafad6b888b152e> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x1863fd000 - 0x186462fff libdispatch.dylib arm64  <37135142d2043b5492d7a49be678b9ae> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x186463000 - 0x18647dfff libdyld.dylib arm64  <4f57dfca63a93930a57d2cea89307b01> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x18647e000 - 0x18647efff liblaunch.dylib arm64  <ca90373a022d3c38ac7ecd736c13bf9b> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x18647f000 - 0x186484fff libmacho.dylib arm64  <25640409947b3e20b1135068c80d8609> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x186485000 - 0x186486fff libremovefile.dylib arm64  <848fca02e8d930fd8659eb188d9bcedd> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x186487000 - 0x18649efff libsystem_asl.dylib arm64  <255a36a954553a278ef2c8711ab62532> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
0x18649f000 - 0x18649ffff libsystem_blocks.dylib arm64  <cbdfd75e23c43610991dc81d325587ea> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x1864a0000 - 0x18651dfff libsystem_c.dylib arm64  <2c43d27314963feb8966491ea64cf5a9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x18651e000 - 0x186522fff libsystem_configuration.dylib arm64  <897ce699a6d73797810d7fe5ceef37d7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
0x186523000 - 0x186528fff libsystem_containermanager.dylib arm64  <ae270ac5b9613cfcb5a6ada4520b8a8b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib
0x186529000 - 0x18652afff libsystem_coreservices.dylib arm64  <c897206125f13042a7f62767de020ae9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
0x18652b000 - 0x18652cfff libsystem_darwin.dylib arm64  <fc17590f3b6f3e2280aa164fe705e624> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_darwin.dylib
0x18652d000 - 0x186533fff libsystem_dnssd.dylib arm64  <2fdef17227d13f49929b104ec635667c> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x186534000 - 0x186571fff libsystem_info.dylib arm64  <c20c44a2d57b330f9931ba840195ee45> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x186572000 - 0x18659afff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64  <6ca465bb9c013f9ab3fb24dd16418142> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x18659b000 - 0x1865c8fff libsystem_m.dylib arm64  <a75c726ec49b3f48b83593be165afcfa> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x1865c9000 - 0x1865e3fff libsystem_malloc.dylib arm64  <cce71425b3483c5fa3718246e8e27ed2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
0x1865e4000 - 0x186684fff libsystem_network.dylib arm64  <cac262c32d6938abb9075481187087c4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x186685000 - 0x186690fff libsystem_networkextension.dylib arm64  <40f740c2ec9b37cebe6043eecbd1927d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
0x186691000 - 0x18669bfff libsystem_notify.dylib arm64  <c204b6b2ef2d38669fb985bc64f26a6b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x18669c000 - 0x1866a5fff libsystem_platform.dylib arm64  <1fd32dd6f1da3029ae0fe5875eaceb94> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
0x1866a6000 - 0x1866b5fff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64  <2f9b440f88eb3cedb786b4b98586d78f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x1866b6000 - 0x1866b9fff libsystem_sandbox.dylib arm64  <001e1a85480c3b07b93861fe7e69843b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x1866ba000 - 0x1866c1fff libsystem_symptoms.dylib arm64  <56e7c311193139968b729073897fbdc6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib
0x1866c2000 - 0x1866d5fff libsystem_trace.dylib arm64  <8b98d3487b6e3b72863670eb57c3b4ff> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
0x1866d6000 - 0x1866dbfff libunwind.dylib arm64  <a9da0d0735093dc38005623608c0f71e> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x1866dc000 - 0x1866dcfff libvminterpose.dylib arm64  <c1577063af17384b8091f9923960a1f1> /usr/lib/system/libvminterpose.dylib
0x1866dd000 - 0x186707fff libxpc.dylib arm64  <1732d812fa793d159965e668759a42df> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x186708000 - 0x186929fff libicucore.A.dylib arm64  <32c272e1e9f735aba4c16a17580f13e3> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x18692a000 - 0x18693bfff libz.1.dylib arm64  <c402ff63470b34df8634f2078cd151e1> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x18693c000 - 0x186cd1fff CoreFoundation arm64  <846f4b1542383c98991c1314902e3d72> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x186cd2000 - 0x186ce2fff libbsm.0.dylib arm64  <b7a56e43a852351d8a2dab94c7fc04e6> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x186ce3000 - 0x186ce3fff libenergytrace.dylib arm64  <6adeca3b70ed33dda70a16353c5ef6ce> /usr/lib/libenergytrace.dylib
0x186ce4000 - 0x186d69fff IOKit arm64  <938f5f32ece43551a651b777bd44d431> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x186d6a000 - 0x186e53fff libxml2.2.dylib arm64  <33530216f58333d993d4acb846c63aac> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x186e54000 - 0x186e61fff libbz2.1.0.dylib arm64  <35c6ddde076638589f755656ac0058ce> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x186e62000 - 0x186e7afff liblzma.5.dylib arm64  <7d5815f117103d15a67fd30b3375b11b> /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
0x186e7b000 - 0x186fd8fff libsqlite3.dylib arm64  <eac933b033d43444ae182e2d7de6137f> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x186fd9000 - 0x186ffffff libMobileGestalt.dylib arm64  <dc43249a916a3294a98ae31871591dd9> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x187000000 - 0x18736cfff CFNetwork arm64  <1b8095865d8a3b84a9cbe0d5d0354fc1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x18736d000 - 0x187668fff Foundation arm64  <dad046ce90513de69c6ca86d7184b7c2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x187669000 - 0x187757fff Security arm64  <11c28a235f0d34a483d4c0c6d3a72617> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x187758000 - 0x1877c4fff SystemConfiguration arm64  <e4021e13feec30af8e612a49060b1ad1> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x1877c5000 - 0x1877fbfff libCRFSuite.dylib arm64  <faed949ffe90353091a2916aef415302> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x1877fc000 - 0x1877fcfff libapple_crypto.dylib arm64  <7b69ce788b6f3bd581d76b857760c614> /usr/lib/libapple_crypto.dylib
0x1877fd000 - 0x187813fff libapple_nghttp2.dylib arm64  <ff88135792b639679509b309f0c0cad9> /usr/lib/libapple_nghttp2.dylib
0x187814000 - 0x18783dfff libarchive.2.dylib arm64  <957aea53942d3afc91420044f6ae5112> /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
0x18783e000 - 0x1878effff libboringssl.dylib arm64  <a515a4c41d7337dd85ed1db0cb3d1a09> /usr/lib/libboringssl.dylib
0x1878f0000 - 0x187907fff libcoretls.dylib arm64  <c2287d06413f32c2aee0e6c3313d98c7> /usr/lib/libcoretls.dylib
0x187908000 - 0x187909fff libcoretls_cfhelpers.dylib arm64  <79276edd953836b698947c5db28c83ad> /usr/lib/libcoretls_cfhelpers.dylib
0x18790a000 - 0x18790bfff liblangid.dylib arm64  <11d94ede5ab1300a820d96e3374f53fa> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x18790c000 - 0x1879dffff libnetwork.dylib arm64  <e4a37ecffec3327bb37e3fd427c92b87> /usr/lib/libnetwork.dylib
0x1879e0000 - 0x187a12fff libpcap.A.dylib arm64  <419a8dd2325a326c81b4b02d849ce562> /usr/lib/libpcap.A.dylib
0x187a13000 - 0x187a47fff libusrtcp.dylib arm64  <227ec64866e53676828e76f89c1e4928> /usr/lib/libusrtcp.dylib
0x187a48000 - 0x187a51fff IOSurface arm64  <76764bfa34e8365e8263c8ec57868e70> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x187a52000 - 0x187af7fff libBLAS.dylib arm64  <05ecdd31f9573a069c0e8b3d610bbc3f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x187af8000 - 0x187e27fff libLAPACK.dylib arm64  <3e55f73c8a4c329d8bb7f5e58ed687c3> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x187e28000 - 0x188094fff vImage arm64  <7fabce5d1fe83c38aa998440146eb09b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x188095000 - 0x1880a6fff libSparseBLAS.dylib arm64  <88335b280db13b3d812ee89998bc363c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libSparseBLAS.dylib
0x1880a7000 - 0x1880cbfff libvMisc.dylib arm64  <20da313fe2343db189a04c72928eb120> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x1880cc000 - 0x1880f6fff libBNNS.dylib arm64  <19481dd658fb3f949cc1874250cfead5> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBNNS.dylib
0x1880f7000 - 0x18810cfff libLinearAlgebra.dylib arm64  <0f6e8d5a7dd8384ebb8a873c2caa7ad7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
0x18810d000 - 0x188111fff libQuadrature.dylib arm64  <124a57c41e3e3956b46e10d49ddf8fe1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libQuadrature.dylib
0x188112000 - 0x188168fff libSparse.dylib arm64  <c7def66b4a4c3f29b55fcbdcf881e3f2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libSparse.dylib
0x188169000 - 0x1881e1fff libvDSP.dylib arm64  <4bf846f47a0e309db93bbbc791720463> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x1881e2000 - 0x1881e2fff vecLib arm64  <86cdd48d842334dd831b1fc0e2b0270f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x1881e3000 - 0x1881e3fff Accelerate arm64  <01d515c3376c332799f14694934ed70b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x1881e4000 - 0x1881f9fff libcompression.dylib arm64  <b1a3a8c4b3a6301da874dc2af4a50920> /usr/lib/libcompression.dylib
0x1881fa000 - 0x18873efff CoreGraphics arm64  <1d111fedd821351f8d22fe4f2840719a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x18873f000 - 0x188744fff IOAccelerator arm64  <ff13ef43a6f73cdaa52ce9abae404d3c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
0x188745000 - 0x18874afff libCoreFSCache.dylib arm64  <ac1882646b0c3cccb69dfc5246995396> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x18874b000 - 0x1887e5fff Metal arm64  <5810b5432e4c34cf9f254b60f64e5e89> /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Metal
0x1887e6000 - 0x1887f9fff GraphicsServices arm64  <208776c1b0a73cb4827546b47cdfca63> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x1887fa000 - 0x188952fff MobileCoreServices arm64  <ceed55b6a3083c1b93152daff0cc2ab5> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x188953000 - 0x188955fff IOSurfaceAccelerator arm64  <4feb745bfd323a0da4357d5fc65f54b2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurfaceAccelerator.framework/IOSurfaceAccelerator
0x188956000 - 0x188997fff AppleJPEG arm64  <823dea35af383cf987bdd6d2b653d41f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleJPEG.framework/AppleJPEG
0x188998000 - 0x188f48fff ImageIO arm64  <090201d1811b3083b64c89e1c9694585> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x188f49000 - 0x188fadfff BaseBoard arm64  <5c05976a04053b179505341ce299f130> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework/BaseBoard
0x188fae000 - 0x188fc5fff AssertionServices arm64  <eac3dcdc35103304b3dc72ce0c8a0a07> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssertionServices.framework/AssertionServices
0x188fc6000 - 0x188fcefff CorePhoneNumbers arm64  <3f42ae84ea833c52b8cd522108d259b2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CorePhoneNumbers.framework/CorePhoneNumbers
0x188fcf000 - 0x189013fff AppSupport arm64  <ac0c26eabc2e3737b4b0f6e524f9c54f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x189014000 - 0x18902cfff CrashReporterSupport arm64  <28a3b2eac04b3ec482639475186d309c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x18902d000 - 0x189032fff AggregateDictionary arm64  <60d5c87dbe3e3c48a3e0b91ae2cad9e7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x189033000 - 0x1890b4fff libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib arm64  <46d5ede9f7fe338c97671721fbad60cc> /usr/lib/libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib
0x1890b5000 - 0x1890d4fff ProtocolBuffer arm64  <8963290d47123204921f70ae9bb9612a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x1890d5000 - 0x189100fff MobileKeyBag arm64  <d8ce3418ab5b3832906e77aa9e3c9aad> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x189101000 - 0x189135fff BackBoardServices arm64  <2b30bebf7da7379db6b6538ca533fd6b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x189136000 - 0x189191fff FrontBoardServices arm64  <5bff8665f950326a8ad86be07a66a48a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
0x189192000 - 0x1891cefff SpringBoardServices arm64  <415fae0b30393d0d92bf23dc22de21c4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x1891cf000 - 0x1891ddfff PowerLog arm64  <83c23c8e972438b79e688c4d455b1b5e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PowerLog.framework/PowerLog
0x1891de000 - 0x1891fbfff CommonUtilities arm64  <dcd92acd9a14345e9b63801706e4a82e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x1891fc000 - 0x189207fff liblockdown.dylib arm64  <2fec7d5a759c32f293936f78220c1fc4> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x189208000 - 0x18950afff CoreData arm64  <b972e9f8b7de3a568acb4ed8216f0b76> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x18950b000 - 0x189511fff TCC arm64  <06384f9076eb3e06a7d2a883d6007b3d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x189512000 - 0x189519fff libcupolicy.dylib arm64  <e6b23e36e1a335ad974f6b35ba2b033b> /usr/lib/libcupolicy.dylib
0x18951a000 - 0x1895a6fff CoreTelephony arm64  <e63112dd995a333ca54d3f6d60ae18c7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x1895a7000 - 0x1895fdfff Accounts arm64  <3f8159d915823051a17536c6b21e81a9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x1895fe000 - 0x189627fff AppleSauce arm64  <4b81009f219e3f3794d3ff93ddcd0547> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleSauce.framework/AppleSauce
0x189628000 - 0x189630fff DataMigration arm64  <e98907cbf67e35ca998fab8c64f92eea> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x189631000 - 0x189637fff Netrb arm64  <9f8ebcf99af53a7087add608b6fb9c2a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Netrb.framework/Netrb
0x189638000 - 0x18966bfff PersistentConnection arm64  <c00b010864ca32d78dadbf487d8fb9f7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x18966c000 - 0x18967dfff libmis.dylib arm64  <1885af6da98d3997abff70b062548010> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x18967e000 - 0x18977efff ManagedConfiguration arm64  <b37e31dfe0b4340f86d707d09f210545> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
```

.... (+ A LOT MORE STUFF) and finishes with:

```
EOF
```

I cannot for the life of me figure the issue here. I am using a framework for maps (`SKMaps`), and when trying to upload the App Store I get errors which go away when I use the build run script seen here:

> [Submit to App Store issues: Unsupported Architecture x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547283/submit-to-app-store-issues-unsupported-architecture-x86)

I have another app on the App Store current being sold which runs the same `SKMaps` framework and build run script. And this app is very similar but 100x more basic, so I'm a little baffled as to why this is getting rejected? Any thoughts?