# iOS Carthage Submit to App Store issues: Unsupported Architecture, Invalid Segment Alignment

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I recieve the following errors when validating my App with 3 frameworks (AlamoFire, SwiftyJSON, SDWebImage).

[image]

[image]

I have implemented the top answers from [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547283/submit-to-app-store-issues-unsupported-architecture-x86)

[image]

And also deleted the simulator image files (i386 and x86_64).  I cannot move past this error and push my App to production.  Is there any solution to solve this problem for me besides the one addressed?

EDIT:

Attached below is my architecture section as well as my linked and embedded libraries and frameworks.

[image: lib and frameworks]

[image: architecture]

Comment: Are you including these frameworks manually or including them with Cocoapods, spm, or the like?

Comment: @PeterDeWeese I am using Cartrhage!

Comment: What do you have entered in your build settings for Architectures and Valid Architectures?

Comment: @PeterDeWeese Updated answer with your reccomendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was resolved by modifying the run script from the generally accepted answer and executing after embedding frameworks.

```
/usr/local/bin/carthage copy-frameworks

#!/usr/bin/env bash

APP_PATH="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${WRAPPER_NAME}"

# This script loops through the frameworks embedded in the application and
# removes unused architectures.
find "$APP_PATH" -name '*.framework' -type d | while read -r FRAMEWORK
do
FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME=$(defaults read "$FRAMEWORK/Info.plist" CFBundleExecutable)
FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH="$FRAMEWORK/$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"

if [ ! -f "${FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH}" ]; then
continue
fi

if xcrun lipo -info "${FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH}" | grep --silent "Non-fat"; then
echo "Framework non-fat, skipping: $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
continue
fi

echo "Thinning framework $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"

EXTRACTED_ARCHS=()

for ARCH in $ARCHS
do
echo "Extracting $ARCH from $FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_NAME"
xcrun lipo -extract "$ARCH" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH" -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH"
EXTRACTED_ARCHS+=("$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-$ARCH")
done

echo "Merging extracted architectures: ${ARCHS}"
xcrun lipo -o "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" -create "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"
rm "${EXTRACTED_ARCHS[@]}"

echo "Replacing original executable with thinned version"
rm "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
mv "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH-merged" "$FRAMEWORK_EXECUTABLE_PATH"
done
```