# Jitsi iOS sdk and Callkit

Tags: ios, objective-c, callkit, jitsi

I am working with JitsiMeet iOS ([Create Jitsi Meet Framework for native iOS application and integrate in Xcode Project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54126696/656600)) for video call implementation in an application. For background mode calling I am trying to achieve a skype like interface. Where user receives an audio call can start talking right away by accepting that call. Hence when I receive `PKPushNotification`, I trigger this code to initiate calling screen:

```
[JMCallKitProxy reportNewIncomingCallWithUUID:activeCallUUID_ handle:message.messageText displayName:message.senderName hasVideo:false completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error)   {
    if (error != nil) NSLog(@"%s error = %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, error.localizedDescription);
}];
```

This works fine and call get triggered as native call. Then I have implemented then I have implemented `JMCallKitListener` and inside `performAnswerCallWithUUID` I tried to initialize my JitsiViewController to joint the call group.

But problem is when application is in background these listeners doesn't trigger. Although they work fine when app is active.