# Cocoapods architectures for .framework bundles

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, x86-64, podspec

I have a `.framework` which I want to distribute through Cocoapods. 
I want to distribute only the binary so the implementation is hidden from users.
Now I am facing an issue where when I try to upload an app using my `.framework` I get an error "ERROR: ITMS-90087: The executable ... contains unsupported architectures '[x86_64]'".
This is understandable since this binary I distribute contains all the architectures for devices and simulators.
Any ideas on how to work around that without asking users to do any additional steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to strip simulator architectures before uploading the app.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41416964/2890168)'s an excellent script to do so.