# Im having problem with the App Store framework distribution and cocoa-pods framework distribution

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods, ios-frameworks

Im trying to distribute my custom build framework via cocoapods, Issue rise when i try to upload my application build with custom framework to Appstore throughs error in image below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRDhR.png "tooltip"

and if i remove x86_64 architecture from the framework its unable to run on simulator.

So my question is:

How can i distribute my framework to work on device, simulator and App store?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you first made a build for a generic IOS device instead of a simulator?
If that is the case do take look at this post which contains a bit about the architecture . You removing the above framework wont probably do it since it is a required one.

[Submit to App Store issues: Unsupported Architecture x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547283/submit-to-app-store-issues-unsupported-architecture-x86)

Let me know if it was of any help if not il look into it