# Xcode how to remove invalid architecture in framework project not in the client app

Tags: swift, xcode, bash, shell

i have ios framework and i am distributing it.
I am not using  dependency management tool like cocoapods.
There is a lot of document that explain how to remove invalid architectures. But all of them i saw making it in client project not in the framework side.

example: https://www.tirupatibalan.com/2019/01/05/create-fat-framework.html

The question is how can i remove invalid architecture in my framework project when client app try to archive?

I don't want add extra script in client app, therefore i must solve this in framework project side

I have a fat library. And i am creating this library with script in build phases with aggregate target.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? You provide fat binaries so that the user can decide which they need.

Comment: I am sorry, i forgot to say that this is an ios framework. So when uploading app store it will give error invalid architecture. Fat library contains arm64 and Intel 64 arcs.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55149540/3937

Comment: You know in xcode 11 linked frameworks and libraries removed. So i chose do not embed my framework and in build phases i removed at embedded frameworks. By the way i tried to made it optional. Bu both of 2 cases it crashes. It says dyld library not loaded when i remove from embedded binaries. When optional, it crashes when try to use library functions.