# PubNub binaries failing submission to app store

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, pubnub

I am getting the following issue when trying to submit my app to app store. The issue has to do with PubNub embedded binaries.

Tried this answer but it didn't work. Haven't got much more online about the issue. [ERROR ITMS-9000: "Unsupported architectures. Your executable contains unsupported architectures '[x86_64, i386]'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25886643/error-itms-9000-unsupported-architectures-your-executable-contains-unsupporte)

Just one thing, switching to Pods is not an option as PubNub with pods won't even validate the file. So the only other way I could get PubNub to work was with embedded binaries and that is what is causing the problem with app store upload.

Also, I got both PubNub and LumberJack built as per: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/swift/pubnub-swift-sdk

If I remove PubNub as embedded binaries it uploads to app store, but then I get the following error.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/CocoaLumberjack.framework/CocoaLumberjack   Referenced from: 
/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/xxxxxx/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/xxxxxx/xxxxxx.app/xxxxxx Reason: image not found (lldb)
```

And bellow are the errors I get when uploading to app store with pubnub embedded binaries.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is definitely something unique with how you are packaging PubNub in your app because there are 100's of PubNub powered iOS apps and many with the latest version of the PubNub iOS SDK - v4.x. Can you provide the details to support@pubnub.com, including your zipped project, so we can take a look?

Comment: For which platform you trying to build? If valuator says, what x86_64 and i386 is not supposed, mean what you try to build iOS/tvOS/watchOS app, but because of some reason built binaries for Mac OS.

Comment: Trying to build for iOS9. Not sure what is wrong here as I built the PubNub & Lumberjack frameworks as PubNub advised to at: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/swift/pubnub-swift-sdk

Comment: Looks like troubles with modulemap which wasn't in place, when .framework bundles has been copied. There is update to copy script in main repository waiting for you to try it.

Comment: Tried the new scripts in main repository and got different errors now. Send and email to PubNub support with prints of the errors. Waiting for feedback at the moment.